# sort by vote with GD STAR RATING plugin

Tags: plugin-gd-star-rating

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can get the sort by vote count to work with the GD STAR RATING plugin? I have added sorting parameters to a category list on my site but it still isn't ordering the posts by the number of thumbs up votes.

http://uhurusoftware.com/category/contest/?gdsr_sort=votes&gdsr_order=asc

Does anyone have suggestions of what I should check? Are there options I need to set in the GD STAR RATING admin panel?

Comment: I had looked over the post that was suggested before I posted my question but I didn't see anything that would help me. For one thing, that post is over 3 years old and many of the links in it no longer work. Second, that post is talking about using code to do queries. I am trying to just use some URL parameters.

Comment: URL query strings don't do anything all by themselves. The code you want to avoid may be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I needed to change the parameter "votes" to "thumbs". I also found it worked better to show the results in a descending order. Here is the working URL:

http://uhurusoftware.com/category/contest/?gdsr_sort=thumbs&gdsr_order=des